# Static and non static access to value

Tags: java, function, casting, static

I have a class called `Packet` and a class called `PacketClientConnecting` witch extends it.   The instances of `PacketClientConnecting` and other packets are stored in `ArrayList<Packet>`.

I want to have access to id value in `static` and `non-static` ways eg `PacketClientConnecting.getStaticId()` or `packetArrayList.get(5).getId()`.

How can i do this without overriding two functions in every class?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Can you have the List in the base class ?

Comment: Does PacketClientConnecting.getStaticId() have a parameter?  What is its type?  If getStaticId(x) just returns x.getId(), then you wouldn't have to override it.  But that's just a guess since I don't really know for sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?
I have to copy two functions (static and non-static) in every packet class.I think this is not the best way of doing this.

Can you have the List in the base class ?
No.

Comment: ^Does PacketClientConnecting.getStaticId() have a parameter?

No, every packet has only one id.I want to get it by class.getId() or
instance.getId().Instances are stored in ArrayList as Packet.

Comment: If ID is an instance variable, having a static method to get it doesn't make any sense. Show us some code.

Comment: If you're extending the `Packet` class, you don't need to copy its functions to the new class. You can access it from objects of the new class as long as they are not private.

Comment: Also, static methods will not be able to access instance variables - that just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a really smooth way of doing this, but one can achieve what you want by using reflection (only once: in the base class):

```
class Packet {

    public static int getStaticId() {
        return 1;
    }

    // This method is virtual and will be inherited without change
    public int getId() {
        try {
            // Find and invoke the static method corresponding 
            // to the run-time instance
            Method getStaticId = this.getClass().getMethod("getStaticId");
            return (Integer) getStaticId.invoke(null);

        // Catch three reflection-related exceptions at once, if you are on Java 7+,
        // use multi-catch or just ReflectiveOperationException
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the subclass all you need is define getStaticId():

```
class PacketClientConnecting extends Packet {
    public static int getStaticId() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Both print 1
        System.out.println(Packet.getStaticId());
        System.out.println(new Packet().getId());

        // Both print 2
        System.out.println(PacketClientConnecting.getStaticId());
        System.out.println(new PacketClientConnecting().getId());
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the overhead of calling reflective operations every time you call getId(), you can use a field in the base class to cache the id:

```
class Packet {

    public static int getStaticId() {
        return 1;
    }

    private final int id = computeId();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // This method runs once per instance created
    private int computeId() {
        try {
            Method getStaticId = this.getClass().getMethod("getStaticId");
            return (Integer) getStaticId.invoke(null);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```